# getSelectedItem JComboBox with GlazedLists AutocompleteSupport Returns Null

Tags: java, autocomplete, nullpointerexception, jcombobox, glazedlists

I'm a bit new to programming so sorry if there is a few things that could have been done better
My combobox is successfully filled with my string array and the auto-complete works fine. I just cant get the text in the combobox.

returns java.lang.NullPointerException

```
private ArrayList<String> arrRekening;
private ArrayList<String> arrEienaar;
private String[] sarrRekening;
private String[] sarrEienaar;

    public NewConnectionPoint() {

    arrAccount = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrOwner = new ArrayList<String>();

    FillCombo(arrAccount , "Owners", "OwnerName");
    FillCombo(arrOwner , "Accounts", "AccountName");
    sarrOwner= arrOwner.toArray(new String[arrOwner .size()]);
    sarrAccount= arrAccount.toArray(new String[arrAccount.size()]);

    JComboBox<String> comboAccount = new JComboBox<String>();
    AutoCompleteSupport<String> supAccount = AutoCompleteSupport.install(comboRekening, GlazedLists.eventList(Arrays.asList(sarrAccount)));
    supAccount.setStrict(true);

    JComboBox<String> comboOwner = new JComboBox<String>();
    AutoCompleteSupport<String> supOwner = AutoCompleteSupport.install(comboOwner,GlazedLists.eventList(Arrays.asList(sarrOwner)));
    supOwner.setStrict(true);

    JButton btnShow = new JButton("ShowSelectedr");
    btnShow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
        //Error occurs at this line 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, comboOwner.getSelectedItem().toString());

    });}
```

}

//Data loaded into arraylists from a Database with sql

```
private void FillCombo(ArrayList<String> ComboElements, String sTable, String sColumn){
try{
    Data.changeQuery(sTable);// database connection fine returns and fills combobox 

    while(MyData.rs.next()){
        String sReturn= MyData.rs.getString(sColumn);
        ComboElements.add(sReturn);
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental difficulty you're experiencing here is that you're trying to leverage the GlazedLists package without properly embracing it's core utility: EventLists.

You can easily side-step your difficulties if you use EventLists rather than ArrayLists.

If you really want to you can keep your `FillCombo` method returning an ArrayList (perhaps better name as `getElements()`) but straight-away initiate an EventList, use the GlazedLists EventComboBoxModel to link the EventList to the JComboBox and then you'll find your combobox getSelectedItem() should work fine.

The modified code to hook a list up to a combobox with autocomplete support will look something like this:

```
...
FillCombo(arrOwner , "Owners", "OwnerName");
EventList<String> ownerEventList = GlazedLists.eventList(arrOwner);
EventComboBoxModel<String> ownerModel = new EventComboBoxModel<String>(ownerEventList);
JComboBox comboOwner = new JComboBox(ownerModel);
AutoCompleteSupport<String> supOwner = AutoCompleteSupport.install(comboOwner,ownerEventList);
supOwner.setStrict(true);
...
```